# declaring a vector as a class member

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

I have simple class in a header file: **a.hh**

```
#ifndef a_hh
#define a_hh

class a
{
public: 
    int i;
    a()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

};
#endif
```

Then i have a  file:**b.cc**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "a.hh"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    a obj;
    obj.i = 10;
    cout << obj.i << endl;
    return 0;
}
>
```

Till this point everything is fine.
I compile the code and it compiles fine.
But as soon  as i add a vector in the class:

```
#ifndef a_hh
#define a_hh

class a
{
public: 
    int i;
    vector < int > x;
    a()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

};
#endif
```

I get a compilation error as below:

```
> CC b.cc
"a.hh", line 7: Error: A class template name was expected instead of vector.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

What is the problem with declaring a vector here as a member?

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: It seems that the compiler doesn't recognize vector. Have you added the include ? And add the std:: namespace to vector

Comment: .. and after including, you should use std::vector

Comment: Yes..even after that i get the same error.

Comment: What's that `a::a()` doing there? That's unnecessary qualification. Remove the `a::`.

Comment: You should learn about and start using constructor initializer lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <vector>` and use the qualified name `std::vector<int>  x;`:

```
#ifndef a_hh
#define a_hh

#include <vector>

class a{
public:
    int i;
    std::vector<int> x;
    a()             // or using initializer list: a() : i(0) {}
    {
        i=0;
    }
};

#endif
```

Other points:

- (as commented by EitanT) I removed the additional qualification `a::` on the constructor
- have a read of [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: @EitanT, I did actually compile it with no problems. But good spot and correct.ed

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did it compile then?

Comment: @EitanT, it (VC2010) seemed to ignore the superfluous qualification but gcc does not http://ideone.com/Iruvc.

Comment: That damn MSVC does it again.

Comment: Not a big deal here, but it may teach good practices to use the initializer list for `i` instead of the delayed assignment.

Comment: @ereOn, I did mention it in the actual code snippet as a comment.

Comment: @EitanT it's a known "extension" in visual studio.

Comment: @J99, it seems then that the disable extensions compiler switch (`/Za`) does really disable all. I compile with it when possible.

Comment: @hmjd: I am trying to create vector of any type (I mean generic vector) of length 10. Please See the code http://ideone.com/c9UY48 . What's wrong in it? Why it fails in compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

declaring a vector as a class member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class class_object 
{
    public:
            class_object() : vector_class_member() {};

        void class_object::add_element(int a)
        {   
            vector_class_member.push_back(a);
        }

        void class_object::get_element()
        {
            for(int x=0; x<vector_class_member.size(); x++) 
            {
                cout<<vector_class_member[x]<<" \n";
            };
            cout<<" \n";
        }

        private:
            vector<int> vector_class_member;
            vector<int>::iterator Iter;
};

int main()
{
    class_object class_object_instance;

    class_object_instance.add_element(3);
    class_object_instance.add_element(6);
    class_object_instance.add_element(9);

    class_object_instance.get_element();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std`, then a.hh just like below:

```
#ifndef a_hh
#define a_hh

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class a
{
public: 
    int i;
    vector <int> x;
    a()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

};
#endif
```

2. If you don't want to only use std namespace in all your code, you can specified  the namespace before type, just like   `std::vector<int> x;`

Comment: It does not matter, if you use the namespace in all you code.

Comment: It does matter. It pollutes the global namespace often causes problem.

Comment: The issue is whether you write your headers for use by anyone who might benefit from your class (in which case your header shouldn't drop the entire contents of `std` into the global namespace). Nawaz has given you -1 in effect for assuming that your header will be used only under the condition that everyone always uses `namespace std`.