# Compiler error undefined symbol

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

I have simple class ina header file:

```
> cat Algorithms.hh
#ifndef Algorithms_hh
#define Algorithms_hh
#include<vector>
class Algorithms
{
public:

Algorithms();
void BubbleSort();

std::vector<int> myarray;

};
#endif
```

Then a corresponding c file:

```
> cat Algorithms.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Algorithms.hh"

Algorithms::Algorithms()
{
myarray.push_back(0);
}


void Algorithms::BubbleSort()
{
      int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
      int temp;             // holding variable
      int numLength = myarray.size(); 
      for(i = 1; (i <= numLength) && flag; i++)
     {
          flag = 0;
          for (j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
         {
               if (myarray[j+1] > myarray[j])      // ascending order simply changes to <
              { 
                    temp = myarray[j];             // swap elements
                    myarray[j] = myarray[j+1];
                    myarray[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
               }
          }
     }
}
>
```

And then the main function:

```
> cat algo2.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Algorithms.hh"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

Algorithms *arr=new Algorithms();
arr->myarray.push_back(1);
arr->myarray.push_back(2);
arr->myarray.push_back(100);
return 0;
}

>
```

When i compile the main:
I get the below error:

```
> CC algo2.cc 
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
Algorithms::Algorithms()              algo2.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
```

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: I thought we *just* agreed [in the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243621/declaring-a-vector-as-a-class-member) that you have to declare the constructor as `Algorithms();` and not as `Algorithms::Algorithms();`?! It's a poor motivation for others to see you brush over their suggestions and plow on regardless.

Comment: The terminating condition for the outer loop is wrong: `for(i = 1; (i <= numLength) && flag; i++)`. Should be `i < numLength`, not `<=`. Also, the parentheses around it are unnecessary. (Yes, I know, the latest versions of gcc warn you if you don't use them; turn off stupid warnings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linker error, the linker is telling you it can't find the definition of constructor of class `Algorithms`. You should compile with:

```
CC Algorithms.cc algo2.cc
```

You can identify it's a linker error because of the `ld:` in front of the error.

And of course as stated by Kerrek SB you need to declare your constructor without the `Algorithms::` in front of it...

Answer (score 0):

You've just forgotten to include both .cc files into compiling:

```
cc algo2.cc Algorithms.cc
```

If you include header file with declarations, like

```
#include "Algorithms.hh"
```

you should also provide implementation, definition in .c, or .lib. or load library with definition dynamically. In your case your library is Algorithms.cc, so just add it into compilation stage, and then both temporary object files

```
Algo2.a + Algorithms.a
```

will go to

```
a.out
```